Initializing LAN9252 as EtherCAT Slave on Toradex iMX7 Colibri Board using spidev library
I'm currently working on implementing EtherCAT communication on the Toradex iMX7 Colibri evaluation board using the spidev library. However, I'm encountering an issue with initializing the LAN9252 as an EtherCAT slave.
When I send a test byte using test_bytes(0x0064), I receive a response of FF FF FF FF FF FF FF, but I should be receiving FF FF FF 21 43 65 87. Can you provide a Python code snippet for initializing the LAN9252 as an EtherCAT slave using the spidev library?

Stack Overflow works the other way around: you are expected to provide your non-working code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
